# Define Position Content Div Overflow Scroll

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to define the position (center), in this case the image div, in the div with overflow?

http://jsfiddle.net/KAy22/1/

```
#scroll-h-v {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
}
.image {
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: relative;
}
```

The Image should on load in the center like this:

[image: center image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may play with top and left position and margin property as below

```
.image {
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: relative;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin-top:-500px;
    margin-left:-500px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KAy22/2/

Hope it helps!

Comment: Yes, right way. But would it possible to see the whole image?

Comment: Do you want to scale image like this http://jsfiddle.net/KAy22/3/ tp occupy width of container

Comment: Actually like this: http://jsfiddle.net/KAy22/1/. But I would like to show section, but would like to scroll the whole image. So the image should set for example top:-300px and left:-300px but without cut the image.

Comment: I guess you may do this quickly with the help of jQuery http://jsfiddle.net/KAy22/5/ but scrolltop and left vals need to calculate as per logic

Comment: No Probs l00per Good Luck :)